# Detecting "surrounded" areas in a binary image

Tags: image-processing

from performing another operation, I get an B/W ( binary ) image which has white and black areas. Now I want to find and floodfill the blacj areas that are completely surrounded by white and not touching the Image border.

The "brute-force" approach i used, which is basically iterating over all pixels( all but the "border" rows/cols), if it finds a black one, I look at the neighbours ( mark them as "visited" ) and if they are black recursively go to their neighbours. And if I only hit white pixels and don't end up at a border I floodfill the area.
This can take a while on a high resolution image.

Is there a not too complicated faster way to to this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a binary image, you can perform a connected component labeling of the black components. All the components found are surrounded with white. Then you go along the borders in order to find the components that touch the border, and you delete them.

An other simpler and faster solution, would be to go along the borders, and as soon as you find a black pixel, you set a seed that expands until all the black pixels that touch the original pixel are white. Doing that, you delete all the black pixels touching the borders. It will remain only the black components that do not touch the borders.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the idea! I used the your second suggestion and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If most black areas are not touching the border, doing the reverse is likely faster (but equally complicated).

From the border mark any reachable pixel (reachable meaning you can get to the border via only black pixels). After this do a pass of the whole image. Anything black and not visited will be a surrounded area.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the answer. If I understood it correctly, your answer is similar to FiReTiTi 's second suggestion. Would mark both as Solutions, but only one works and can't upvote yet!